# Solving Infinite Sum of Poisson

Tags: statistics, poisson-distribution

Currently, whenever I encounter Poisson questions in the form of $P(X\ge x)$, I am forced to use

$P(X\ge x) =1-P(X\lt x)$

$1 - (P(X= 0) + P(X= 1) + P(X= 2) + ...+ P(X= x-1))$.

If in the future, I get a question where the given $x$ is large. Then I can't sum them individually, but I don't know how to solve the infinite sum or maybe there is other methods?

i.e.

Poisson(2)

$P(K\ge100)$

$=\sum_{k=100}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-2}2^k}{k!}$

$=$  ... ?

Comment: If the Poisson mean is large enough for $P(X > x)$ with large $x$ to be substantial, then maybe use normal approximation. Sometimes for small mean and $x$ a binomial approx works. And then of course there's software. // There is a [connection](http://www.stat.ucla.edu/~nchristo/statistics100B/stat100b_poisson_gamma.pdf) btw Poisson and gamma, more of theoretical interest than computational.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of normal appoximation:

Let $X \sim \mathsf{Pois}(\lambda = 100);$ find $P(X > 90):$
$$P(X > 90) = 1-P(X \le 90) = 1-P(X \le 90.5) =
1-P\left(\frac{X-\lambda}{\sqrt{\lambda}} \le \frac{90.5 - 100}{10}\right)\\
\approx 1-P(Z \le -0.95) = 0.8289,$$

where $Z$ is standard normal. The computation in R statistical software below shows the exact answer:

```
1 - ppois(90,100)
## 0.8286149
```

Nowadays, it seems that software is the practical way to compute many Poisson probabilities.
In my view the normal approximation, relying as it does on printed tables or software,
is not more *genuine mathematics* than using readily available software. 
However, for proving some theorems, relationships among normal, gamma, binomial, and Poisson distributions can be very useful.

Comment: Ooooh yeah, so that's why we learn approximations. I was thinking why approximate distributions when we could find the real thing.